# How to read in XML files with multiple root elements in R?

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I've been thrust a bunch of XML files which are not well formed. They all have multiple root elements. Both `xmlParse` in `XML` and `read_xml` in `xml2` packages barf when I try to use them to read them in with `Error: 1: Extra content at the end of the document`. Is there a package that makes reading multiple root elements easy, or do I need to resort to more brutish methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xml` standard does not support multiple root messages.

I would advice you to read this content as a string, wrap with single root and pass to any of xml `r` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Try `read_html` in the xml2 package can read it adding some tags.  Here is an example:

```
library(xml2)
s <- "<xyz>1</xyz><xyz>2</xyz>"
doc <- read_html(s)
```

giving:

```
> doc
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <body>\n  <xyz>1</xyz>\n  <xyz>2</xyz>\n</body>
```

Now we can operate on `doc`, e.g.

```
> xml_find_all(doc, "//xyz")
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <xyz>1</xyz>
[2] <xyz>2</xyz>
```

This also works with the XML package:

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(s, asText= TRUE, useInternal = TRUE)
xpathSApply(xmlRoot(doc), "//xyz", xmlValue)
```

giving:

```
[1] "1" "2"
```